# What is this symbol called =>

Tags: php, symbols

What is this => symbol Called in PHP. I know it can be interpret as Equal Sign Right Angle Bracket. | can be called Pipe or OR. but my prof was asking the other term to call the => symbol. It is for assigning a value to a key in array class. does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: The ruby people used to call it `hashrocket` but i doubt that this is the answer you are looking for. (-:

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: thanks for giving an idea :) I hope someone can figure it out though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Does This Mean in PHP -> or =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's officially being called `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Thanks I guess we call it T_DOUBLE_ARROW then :)

Answer (score 2):

It is an [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) 
There are no official names but, if you come across any PHP Error referring to non-associative key then, PHP error calls it [T_DOUBLE_ARROW](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

Comment: Thanks I guess we call it T_DOUBLE_ARROW then :)

Comment: at work, I just call it "point-key" however, that's not official ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is an assignment operator. Right associativity.

Answer (score 0):

I've often heard it referred to (atleast in the perl world) as a "double barrelled arrow".