# What does this mean in PHP: -> or =>

Tags: php, syntax

I see these in PHP all the time but I don't have a clue as to what they actually mean. What does `->` do and what does `=>` do. And I'm not talking about the operators. They're something else, but nobody seems to know...

Comment: @Harry: Google doesn't work too well with symbols: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+%3D>

Comment: It's not super helpful for a question to be marked as "duplicate" with a link to a question which is closed for being unhelpful.

Comment: @Harry it works in 2021, searching 'php  =>' brought me here

Answer (score 414):

The **double arrow operator**, `=>`, is used as an access mechanism for arrays. This means that what is on the left side of it will have a corresponding value of what is on the right side of it in array context. This can be used to set values of any acceptable type into a corresponding index of an array. The index can be associative (string based) or numeric.

```
$myArray = array(
    0 => 'Big',
    1 => 'Small',
    2 => 'Up',
    3 => 'Down'
);
```

The **object operator**, `->`, is used in object scope to access methods and properties of an object. It’s meaning is to say that what is on the right of the operator is a member of the object instantiated into the variable on the left side of the operator. Instantiated is the key term here.

```
// Create a new instance of MyObject into $obj
$obj = new MyObject();
// Set a property in the $obj object called thisProperty
$obj->thisProperty = 'Fred';
// Call a method of the $obj object named getProperty
$obj->getProperty();
```

Comment: So -> is like the . in JAVA.

Comment: So -> is like the . in Ruby too :)

Comment: So -> is like the . in Javascript :)

Comment: So `->` is like the `.` in ColdFusion :)

Comment: So `->` is like `.` in Python too :D

Comment: So `->` is like `->` in C++

Comment: Note Bene : -> is completely unlike . in brainfuck.

Comment: So -> is like the . in PowerShell :)

Comment: So -> is like . in Golang too :D

Comment: So `->` is not like `['brackedNotation]` in PHP and JavaScript ?

Comment: So `->` is like the `.` in C# :)

Comment: Use -> operator to "access" Object Properties , Use => operator to "assign" values to an Object Property.

Comment: :: is also like . in Java but only when accessing method or variable statically. Math.PI in java would be Math::PI in PHP (if there was a Math class with a PI variable)

Comment: So -> is like . in TS

Comment: So -> is like . in C++

Comment: So -> is like . in most languages?

Comment: So -> is like . in Lua

Comment: So -> is like . in TypeScript

Comment: So -> is like . in MQL XD.

Comment: So -> is like -> in c++ for pointer of object and . for object itself

Comment: So -> is like . in Lua

Comment: so I up vote all the comment like the . (dot : less typing means do more)

Comment: Why didn't PHP follow the . syntax?

Comment: @shalomew if they did, we wouldn't have this glorious thread.

Comment: So `->` is like `.` in GDScript?

Answer (score 80):

`->` is used to call a method, or access a property, on the object of a class

`=>` is used to assign values to the keys of an array

E.g.:

```
    $ages = array("Peter"=>32, "Quagmire"=>30, "Joe"=>34, 1=>2);
```

And since **PHP 7.4**+ the operator `=>` is used too for the added [*arrow functions*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php), a more concise syntax for [*anonymous functions*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 51):

`=>` is used in associative array key value assignment.  Take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

`->` is used to access an object method or property.  Example: `$obj->method()`.

Answer (score 31):

**->**

calls/sets object variables.
Ex:

```
$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->foo = 'bar';
var_dump($obj);
```

**=>**
Sets key/value pairs for arrays. Ex:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
);
var_dump($array);
```