# What are the combination of operators are called?

Tags: coding-style

I recently came across some practice used by programmers for better readability, I am having trouble finding it. It goes like this,
"Instead of using => in hashes you can use a symbolic array ->" and same for other operators. What's it called? I googled for 1 hour and went through most of the hacker news.

Comment: Most of the languages were supported. Do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: In this case, I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Does This Mean in PHP -> or =>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or)