# What is meant by '->' in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am going through the example

```
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       }

      $sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
         if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "Database created successfully";
         } else {
          echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
        }
```

What is the meaning of the symbol `->` in the above example

Comment: Existing topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or

Comment: ->, is used when you want to call a method on an instance or access an instance property

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has two object operators.

The first, `->` , is used when you want to call a method on an instance or access an instance property.

The second, `::`, is used when you want to call a static method, access a static variable, or call a parent class's version of a method within a child class.

**source:** [Where do we use the object operator "->" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-do-we-use-the-object-operator-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, **->** operator is used for call member function or member variable.