# Not getting any values in downloadable excel file generated using PHPexcel plugin

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to use PHPexcel plugin to generate downloadable excel file from mysql data. Unfortunately, I am only getting only the column headers and not their values in the downloaded excel file

Where am I going wrong ? Also, I would like unicode characters to show properly.
Following is my code of the downloadexcel.php file -

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$data=array();

$sql="SELECT s.t_id,s.t_text,p.user_name,p.description,s.time,p.place from t 
AS s INNER JOIN users AS p ON s.user_name=p.user_name order by s.time desc";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {
    $array=array("T Link" => $row[0],"T"=>$row[1] , "User Name" => $row[2] , 
"User Profile" => $row[3], "Time" => $row[4] , "Place" => $row[5]);
     array_push($data,$array);
  }

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'T Link');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'T');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'User Name');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'User Profile');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'Time');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'Place');

$row=2;
foreach($data as $row->$value) {
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row,$value->t_id);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row,$value->t_text);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row,$value->user_name);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$row,$value->description);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$row,$value->time);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$row,$value->place);
    $row++;
}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Based on comments of Mark Baker, edited the code but still not getting any result. This is my **edited code** -

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$data=array();

$sql="SELECT s.t_id,s.t_text,p.user_name,p.description,s.time,p.place from t 
AS s INNER JOIN users AS p ON s.user_name=p.user_name order by s.time desc";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'T Link');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'T');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'User Name');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'User Profile');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'Time');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'Place');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
$n=2;
foreach($data as $row) {
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$n,$row['t_id']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$n,$row['t_text']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$n,$row['user_name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$n,$row['description']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$n,$row['time']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$n,$row['place']);
    $n++;
   }
}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: The __array__ that you're pushing into $data bears no resemblance to the __model__ that you're accessing in `foreach($data as $row->$value)`

Comment: $row is being used for the row number; but also as some form of model holder: `$row=2;
foreach($data as $row->$value) {`

Comment: That's 2 problems with your code; both of which will prevent it from working correctly

Comment: It's also highly inefficient building an array by looping through the data, then looping through that array to build the spreadsheet data

Comment: If I write `$row=2; foreach($data as $value)` still getting same result

Comment: @MarkBaker, Can you please suggest right code in the answer ?

Comment: Edited my code but still not working, Please see

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
foreach($data as $row->$value) {
```

to

```
foreach($data as $row => $value) {
```

"->" operator is used with objects. The difference between the two operators is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14037376/577778

**Updated Code**

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$data=array();

$sql="SELECT s.t_id,s.t_text,p.user_name,p.description,s.time,p.place from t 
AS s INNER JOIN users AS p ON s.user_name=p.user_name order by s.time desc";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'T Link');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'T');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'User Name');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'User Profile');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'Time');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'Place');

$n=2;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$n,$row['t_id']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$n,$row['t_text']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$n,$row['user_name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$n,$row['description']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$n,$row['time']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$n,$row['place']);
    $n++;
}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: Q Hussain Please see my edited code. That however is not working

Comment: In the modified code, I don't think you need "foreach" anymore. Try running the code after removing it. Furthermore, inside "while" block try to print the value of $row['t_id']. Are you sure your query returns some result?

Comment: If I remove foreach , then how can I fetch subsequent rows ?

Comment: As I can see from the modified code "$data" is an empty array and there is no elements in it. The rows will be fetched by "mysqli_fetch_array($result)" through the variable "$row" (which is an array of columns) and "foreach" in this situation overwrites the variable "$row" which has the actual data.

Comment: Can You write the correct code in your opinion @Mohammed Q Hussain in your answer ?

Comment: Thanks. I updated your code for the connection line and added it. It gave me an error - "Excel cannot open the file 'helloworld.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file as not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file" Opening the file with a text editor, I found an empty line at the beginning (did not find the reason for it). I removed that line and saved the file and opened it in excel. It is showing only 2 rows - first row with the titles and the second row with the content of one row of mysql database

Comment: I added `ob_end_clean();` to the code and it removed the error while opening file. But now only issue is that I get only two rows in the excel sheet - one of the header and another a row from the mysql database. Please see.

Comment: Are you sure that your query should return more than one row? You can check that easily using phpMyAdmin or by printing some values under "while" block.

Comment: I ran the query in phpMyAdmin and it returned more than 23,000 rows. So, there is no issue with query.

Comment: I haven't notice that. The line which initializes $n with 2 must be outside the loop. I updated the code in the answer. Please try it, it must work fine now.

Comment: When I did that, it is giving only the row with titles

Comment: Can you please make a sqlfiddle and see if it works ?

Comment: Hi. I have tried a the code in my machine (with different database) and it worked fine. Can you create a new PHP page and run the same query and print the result instead of sending them to PHPExcel. See if there is more than one row will be printted.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I echoed this and it is giving all the results on the page from mysql database (I removed the phpexcel sending code)

echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$n."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['t_id']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['t_text']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['user_name']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['time']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['place']."</td>";
echo'</tr>";

Comment: There was an issue with memory it seems and adding some code on it solved the problem. Please update it in your answer and let me know and I will choose your answer as right one
`set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`
`$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize' => '100MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);`