# What is => in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

just a simple question

In this example, what does `=>` do? and how to read it?

is it read by "is to" or "is equal"

```
$array = array(
    'color' => 'red',
    'shape' => 'round',
    'radius' => '10',
    'diameter' => '20'
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Does This Mean in PHP -> or =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its not `is to` or `is equal` but the sign `=>` is an assignment operator  to assign values in array's indexes.

For example:

```
$x[0] = 10;
$x[1] = 20;
$x[2] = 30;
$x[3] = 40;
```

Or

```
$x = (0 => 10,
      1 => 20,
      2 => 30,
      3 => 40,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`=>` separates key and value pairs in PHP array. It is not related to Codeigniter. See more details about PHP array from this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).