# Laravel regex validation for price OR empty

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to make a regex for price OR empty.
I have the price part (Dutch uses comma instead of point) which actualy works

```
/^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$/
```

The regex above validates ok on the value 21,99

Now I try to add the empty part so the field can be... just empty ^$

```
/(^$|^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$)/
```

But Laravel starts to complain as soon as I change the regex: 
"Method [validate^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$)/] does not exist."

Works ok:

```
$rules = [
    'price' => 'regex:/^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$/'
];
```

Laravel says no...:

```
$rules = [
    'price' => 'regex:/(^$|^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$)/'
];
```

Kenken9990 answer - Laravel doesn't break anymore but an empty value is still wrong:

```
$rules = [
    'price' => 'regex:/^(\d+(,\d{1,2})?)?$/'
];
```

Comment: Can you add a valid & invalid patterns, from which regex need to validate.

Comment: In php are you able to use a regex like a lambda function? I didn't think you could.

Comment: @emsimpson92 I am not a programmer,  a Lambda?

Comment: My apologies, I meant an anonymous function. `=>` is C# syntax for exactly that. It looks like it has [a different meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or) in PHP. Your problem is with the `=>`

Comment: @emsimpson92 In PHP you create an array like that. Example 1 works, example 2 fails. It's just the regex I think, or Laravel..., oh and now I know what you mean with Lamba, something with passing a value to a function or something?

Comment: Yes, but you're assigning a keyvaluepair with the key `price` and value `your regex`. the regex is not your value, just the pattern you want to run the value through

Answer (score 9, accepted):

is this work ?

```
$rules = [
    'price' => 'nullable|regex:/^(\d+(,\d{1,2})?)?$/'
];
```

Comment: You are my hero, I 54ck at regex

Comment: what a bummer, it doesn;t break anymore but still it's says an empty value is not OK, but it should

Comment: @poashoas Add `'nullable'`

Comment: submit a empty input will change to null, means set to nullable and no need regex for the empty part

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that should be an answer, not just a comment

Comment: sorry for i test it on pure php code preg_match(), and i forgot empty input will change to null, @WiktorStribiżew that should be an answer

Comment: @poashoas If you read documentations, you would have found the answer earlier than somebody else that googled it for you.

Comment: @revo and you just got here to tell me how dissapointed you are in me?

Comment: @poashoas Not really. The point is reading manuals prevents people from being surprised mistakenly.

Comment: @revo sorry for my angry response, but it makes somebody feel stupid. Stackoverflow is a place to ask silly questions too. And yes, I do read documentation but it didn't popped my mind, I was to busy with the regex.

Comment: @poashoas I didn't call your knowledge into question.

Answer (score 2):

`|` is also the separator for multiple validation rules.

For example the following is valid:

```
 $rules = [ "price" => "nullable|numeric|between:0,99" ];
```

To use it regex you need to switch to using an array:

```
$rules = [
    'price' => [ 'regex:/(^$|^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$)/' ]
];
```

This is also pointed out in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex):

> Note: When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

Incidentally the original rule might also do what you want and can also be written as:

```
$rules [
     'price' => [ 'nullable', 'numeric', 'between:0,99' ]
]
```