# What are these arrows inside of an array called?

Tags: php

Noob question I guess...
I just want to know what this sort of thing is called.

My guess is that acf_add_options_page is a function that's taking an array of values. I just want to know the name of these arrow things inside of an array is...

```
acf_add_options_page(array(
  'page_title'  => 'General Settings',
  'menu_title'  => 'General Settings',
  'position' => '63.3',
));
```

Comment: php associative array.it help you store value in key value pair

Comment: Afaik, they are assignment operators.

Comment: This might help you a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or#:~:text=The%20double%20arrow%20operator%2C%20%3D%3E,corresponding%20index%20of%20an%20array.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This type of array is called an associative array. This helps you in a case where you need to define your own key as the index of the array. Let's say you want to print a users list where the User model/entity/table has the following column name:

- name
- email
- phone

Rather than printing the array as `$user[0]` you can call it `$user['name']`
It's not only typed-friendly but also helps you to avoid collapse.
There might be cases where email is retrieved before the name column. You are expecting something like this:

```
0 => 'John Doe',
1 => 'john@example.com',
2 => '0999999999'
```

But end up with something like this:

```
 0 => 'John Doe',
 1 => '0999999999',
 2 => 'john@example.com'
```

To avoid those cases you can print/access them by their key defined by you. In such cases, you don't have to follow the serial. Just print them according to their key name.

```
// no need to remember the index
"name"  => 'John Doe',
"phone" => '0999999999',
"email" => 'john@example.com'
```

For more you can give it a read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Based on the title: _"What are these arrows inside of an array called?"_, they are asking what the symbol `=>` are called, not what type of array it is.

Answer (score -4):

`=>` is called assignment operator. It is use to assign value on right hand side to the Key on the left hand side.

For example

```php
“fname”=>“Alhaji” 
“age”=>“25”
```

They are use in associative array